# ViewPager shows duplicate page error

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I spent whole day for searching the right answer, but couldn't find any.

I have a ViewPager which has listview on each fragment, and it keep showing duplicate data on first and second page. (sometimes other two pages, i.e. second and third)

Let's say I have A,B,C,D,E listviews on each fragment, but when I started my ViewPager, it shows B,B,C,D,E. I guess this is because `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` is automatically loads previous and next page, and in my case, it seems like last loaded data is over writing the previous data.

Here's my adapter :

```
private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private ArrayList<MyFragment> mMyFragList;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<MyFragment> list) {
        super(fm);
        mMyFragList = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
       return mMyFragList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public MyFragment getItem(int position) {
       return mMyFragList.get(position);
    }

}
```

and ViewPager initialize part :

```
public void updateView() {
    setPagerFragment(); 
    mPager = (ViewPager) mView.findViewById(R.id.menu_viewpager);
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager(), mMyFrag);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

public void setPagerFragment() {
    for(int i=0; i<mListData.size(); i++) {
        // mListData is an ArrayList of MyPojo object
        MyFragment fragment = MyFragment.newInstance(i, mListData.get(i));
        mMyFrag.add(fragment);
  }
}
```

This `updateView()` function is called from another class as a callback, and I checked `mListData` has correct data before and after assign to Fragment.

Also, here's the `newInstance()` in MyFragment :

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(int page, MyPojo data) {

    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    String jsonObj = gson.toJson(data);
    bundle.putInt(ARG_PAGE_NUMBER, page);
    bundle.putString(ARG_PAGE_DATA, jsonObj);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;
}
```

When I checked `page` and `data` in `newInstance()` and `onCreate()` of `MyFragment`, the page index and its data were correct.

I tried all the variation of above code, i.e. using `FragmentPagerAdapter` or `initialize and destroy fragment manually in adapter` and etc, but none of them worked for me.

Is there anyone who can share your wisdom?

Comment: can you post code of one of your fragment say `A`?

Comment: @mmlooloo If you see `setPagerFragment()`, all fragments are instance of `MyFragment`, and the difference between A and B is data.

Comment: post the code that you initialize `ArrayList<MyFragment> mMyFragList;`

Comment: @mmlooloo the code is already posted, please see the constructor.